# jquery image pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have list of images in my jsp file that i want to display 5 at a time with pagination. How to do this using jquery?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick demo, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmoulin/dAeyV/15/).

The prev and next link are optional.
Just change the "var start = 0" if needed.

HTML

```
<div class="img-list">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
    <img src="" alt="2" />
    <img src="" alt="3" />
    <img src="" alt="4" />
    <img src="" alt="5" />
    <img src="" alt="6" />
    <img src="" alt="7" />
    <img src="" alt="8" />
    <img src="" alt="9" />
    <img src="" alt="10" />
    <img src="" alt="11" />
    <img src="" alt="12" />
    <img src="" alt="13" />
    <img src="" alt="14" />
    <img src="" alt="15" />
</div>
<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
```

jQuery

```
var start = 0;
var nb = 5;
var end = start + nb;
var length = $('.img-list img').length;
var list = $('.img-list img');

list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();


$('.prev, .next').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   if( $(this).hasClass('prev') ){
       start -= nb;
   } else {
       start += nb;
   }

   if( start < 0 || start >= length ) start = 0;
   end = start + nb;       

   if( start == 0 ) list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();
   else list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+'):gt('+(start-1)+')').show();
});
```

Comment: it's working in the demo, the alt is displayed since the sources are empty, you just need to fill the "src" attribute for the images.

Comment: yes i filled the src with images. images are displaying. But pagination is not happened. though i checked with jsFiddler.

Comment: my code is same like your code. i dont change anything. just i filled with image in src...

Comment: Ok. You have to include the jquery javascript file in your html code and wrap the javascript code in a $(document).ready(function(){ ... });


So <script src="jquery.js"></script> and <script> $(document).ready(function(){ /*code here*/ });</script>

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to say image slider. Check the link I googled.

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the JSP to accept two parameters (e.g. startImg, howMany), and based on those parameters output some HTML to inject into the page:

```
$("a.pageNumber").click(function() {
    $.get('images.jsp', {startImg: $(this).text(), howMany: 5}, function(response) {
        $("#imageDiv").html(response); // response contains some <img/> tags
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: will it display all the iamges from the jsp file? can u explain in brief?