# Pagination in jquery or jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am developing an app where i need to implement pagination for changing of images. The code i am using is.

index.html

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="imagesScreen" id="imagesScreen">

            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            <img style="border-radius:10px;height:70px;width:70px;margin:10px;" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />              
</div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Here as per above code i am having two buttons in footer tag(not mentioned code above). in each page i want to display around 6-10 images & when i click next button or previous button in the same page data needs to be change using Pagination technique. Here i took static data, but in my app that data comes from server during runtime. so, i need to create dynamic data.

As per the link [Pagination link](http://thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm) here getting one image at a time. but i want around 6-10 images as per the below picture. when i click on next button page need to be same but data must change as per the [Pagination link](http://thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm).

[image]
Can anyone please help me with this how to get that type of pagination technique & how to create dynamic data of div & image tags( &  tags), as i want the view as per the below blackberry image shown.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260029/jquery-image-pagination.You can get image links from servers.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fairly logical feature. First, I'm assuming you're pulling data with SQL using a limit
    SELECT * FROM `images` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 0, 9

I'm assuming you're using PHP for the server-side scripting, if not, try accommodating this to your language.
Let's say we have a `GET` value that uses `page=123` for the page ID, of course `123` is an arbitrary number; we need to pull the images starting at `page number * items per page` so for example, at page `2`, we get `2 * 9` which is `18`, so our first picture should be picture `18`. Now I just go on taking the correct `LIMIT` clause in the SQL query:

PHP:

```
$start = $_GET['page'] * $items_per_page;
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `images` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$items_per_page}
```

That's the basic gist of it.

Comment: Very similar to what i was about to answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below URL as a reference.

http://cssglobe.com/lab/easypaginate/02.html

Thanks