# Image Gallery with Pagination Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, pagination

Want to display 4 images in a row and 3 rows in a page. So totally 12 images in a page..
In image gallery, if I have more than 12 imges, need to implement pagination.

Hardly tried to get the links or sources or plugins to achieve this.
I have no idea how to do this. am new to jquery.
 kinldy help me on this.

Comment: I think you could find your answer in this thread here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260029/jquery-image-pagination

Comment: No @MitkoDelibaltov .. I have already reviewed this link. However the pagination should have numbers in it incuding the prev and Next links. this has been answered 9 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, could you consider this soluton:

My fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/u4y1t6ga/1/

I have setuped it for 2x2, but you can modify it as you wish.

If you wish to update it to 12 - 3 rows x 4 each
in JS update nb = 12
in CSS update n-th child to be 4n+1

HTML:

```
<div class="img-list">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
    <img src="" alt="2" />
    <img src="" alt="3" />
    <img src="" alt="4" />
    <img src="" alt="5" />
    <img src="" alt="6" />
    <img src="" alt="7" />
    <img src="" alt="8" />
    <img src="" alt="9" />
    <img src="" alt="10" />
    <img src="" alt="11" />
    <img src="" alt="12" />
</div>
<a href="#" class="prev">Page 1</a>
<a href="#" class="next">Page 2</a>
```

CSS:

```
.img-list, .pagination
{
  float: left;
  clear:both;
  display: block;
}

.img-list img {
 float: left;
}

.img-list img:nth-child(4n-1) {
 clear:both;
}
```

JS (+jQuery)

```
var start = 0;
var nb = 4;
var end = start + nb;
var length = $('.img-list img').length;
var list = $('.img-list img');

list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();


$('.prev, .next').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if (($(this).hasClass('prev') && start > 0) || ($(this).hasClass('next') && end < length))
  {

    if( $(this).hasClass('prev') ){
      start -= nb;
    } else {
      start += nb;
    }

    end = start + nb;

    if((start/nb) < 1)
    {
      $('a.prev').html('Page 1');
    }
    else
    {
      $('a.prev').html('Page '+(start/nb));
    }


    if(end+nb > length) {
      $('a.next').html('Page '+((end/nb)));
    } else {
      $('a.next').html('Page '+((end/nb)+1));
    }
  }

  if( start == 0 ) list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();
  else list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+'):gt('+(start-1)+')').show();
});
```

In case you need some more complex solution I would advice you to use already created plugin. Something like this one: https://pagination.js.org/
and just update the css to show the elements in the expected way. (i.e. push elements in 3 rows x 4 images on each row).